# Is it possible to view the contents of a debian package?

Tags: package-management

I want to see the contents of a debian package, especially if the package is properly cleaning up whatever it installs.

I want to also see how it goes about installing the software, what directories it creates, symbolic links etc.

Answer (score 50):

Use

```
dpkg -x somefile.deb somefolder
```

to extract the file that `somefile.deb` contains into folder `somefolder`

Use

```
dpkg -e somefile.deb somefolder
```

to extract the control data (package scripts, metadata,...) of `somefile.deb` into folder `somefolder`.

Some archive manager let you just browser Debian packages like any other archive file.

Answer (score 39):

You can use `dpkg` in a terminal to see which files are in an installed package.

```
dpkg -L <package>
```

You can also use it to find out which package a specific file came from.

```
dpkg -S <file>
```

To list the content of a .deb-file.

```
dpkg -c <file.deb>
```

In order to evaluate what pre/post-install actions are taken these files need to be extracted and manually viewed.

```
dpkg -e <file.deb> [folder]
```

See the man-page for `dpkg` for more options.

Answer (score 10):

There is `dpkg -c package.deb`, which lists the files installed by the package, and `dpkg --info package.deb`, which shows general information including which configuration scripts exist (these are run at various points during installation).

In addition, it is rather difficult for a .deb package to not clean up installed files, because these are tracked automatically, except for files created from scripts. Debian has the [piuparts](https://wiki.debian.org/piuparts) service, which tests this automatically for packages in the Debian archive.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is. A Debian package is in fact only an archived folder. So you should be able to open it with the default Archive Manager (right click -> Open with Archive Manager
). Optionally, you can also extract wherever you want. I hope you will be able to learn a lot from doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's just a normal AR archive, like tar part in tar.gz files (Tape ARchive in that case)

Contents of this archive are three files:

- debian-binary: deb format version number. This is "2.0" for current versions of Debian.
- control.tar.gz: all package meta-information. It tells dpkg what to configure when the package is being installed.
  data.tar, data.tar.gz, data.tar.bz2, data.tar.lzma or data.tar.xz: the actual installable files.
- The debian-binary file must be the first entry in the archive, otherwise it will not be recognized as a Debian package.

You can see this for yourself with `ar t yourpackage.deb`.

Answer (score 3):

For installed packages you can see a list of the directories and files it creates as well as the scripts that are used for installation and removal in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.  All the files are named based on the package.  Various extensions indicate the files purpose.

These files can also be found in the `.deb` which can be viewed with an archive viewer.   I tend to use `mc` from the command line.